# Is it possible to give anchor an alias in markdown?

Tags: github, markdown

I am wondering if it is possible to give anchor an alias name.

for example:

```
## a very looooooooooooooooooooooooooong string
```

How can I refer to the long anchor with a short alais?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can revert back to raw HTML:

```
<h2 id="short-string">a very looooooooooooooooooooooooooong string</h2>
```

And then you can link to it elsewhere with:

```
Link to [a very looooooooooooooooooooooooooong string](#short-string).
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, at least in the popular R markdown version (aka. Pandoc's markdown)

Not sure which flavour of markdown you are using but I did use this specific feature in several of my past R-markdown reports in the past.

Referring to the [RStudio markdown cheatsheet v2.0](https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/rmarkdown-cheatsheet-2.0.pdf):

`# Header1 {#anchor}`

then

`Jump to [Header 1](#anchor)`

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Sorry I didn't mention that I am using github. It seems that this syntax doesn't work in github.